# The correct way of using jQuery index() ; ? Its always returning -1

Tags: jquery, function, indexing

Not sure why this is happening. But everytime I do `(elem).index();` , it always returns `-1` . Why is that?

How can I find the index of an object?

Comment: That means the element is not found.  Please post sample HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at [ **this example usage** ](http://jsfiddle.net/N3MfU/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`jQuery.index()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/), among a lot of examples:

> ### *Return Values*
>
> If no argument is passed to the `.index()` method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.
>
> If `.index()` is called on a collection of elements and a DOM element or jQuery object is passed in, `.index()` returns an integer indicating the position of the passed element relative to the original collection.
>
> If a selector string is passed as an argument, `.index()` returns an integer indicating the position of the original element relative to the elements matched by the selector. **If the element is not found, `.index()` will return -1.**

Note the last sentence. Apparently `elem` is simply not found. Verify your selector and/or the element.

---

**Update** as per the comments, you're likely calling it at the wrong moment. Here's an SSCCE, copy'n'paste'n'run it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 3740385</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            alert('Before DOM ready: ' + $(".nav ul li:first").index()); // Can return -1.

            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('After DOM ready: ' + $(".nav ul li:first").index()); // Must return 0.
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### See also:

- [`jQuery.ready()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: But it can select it in firebug, so my selectors work, but it still gives me -1. Here's an example, `$(".nav ul li:first").index();` returns -1, but $(".nav ul li:first") is a working selector.

Comment: It gives 0 here. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ujcaf/). Probably you're calling it at the wrong moment (before the DOM has loaded). Put it in `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Maybe its an old version of js I'm using or it doesn't work in firebug. I'm using this instead `$(".nav ul li:first").prevAll().length;`

Comment: Just use the latest. You can use the script URL as in the above example. You're free to include it in your pages, it's from a [CDN](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery).

Comment: Yah thanks, something bigger at stake here is probably preventing this from working. Thanks anyway.